# Laravel - Access additional column data within a pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I have an additional column in a pivot table, and I need to access it.

**Schema:**

```
Schema::create('alert_criteria', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('alert_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('alert_id')->references('id')->on('alerts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('criteria_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('criteria_id')->references('id')->on('criterias')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('viewed');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Criteria Modal**

```
public function alerts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Alert')->withPivot('viewed')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getMatches()
{
    $matches = Criteria::find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->alerts()
    ->get();
}
```

**View:**

```
  @foreach($matches as $match)
    <td>{{$match->viewed}}</td>
  @endforeach
```

The view doesn't return an error but it just doesn't show anything. The 'viewed' column is just 1 or 0.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access additional pivot table columns add this to your relationship declaration:

```
public function alerts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Alert')->withPivot('viewed');
}
```

To then access it you have to use the `pivot` property

```
@foreach($matches as $match)
    <td>{{$match->pivot->viewed}}</td>
@endforeach
```

[Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

Comment: Within my `Criteria` model, I now have `public function alerts()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Alert')->withPivot('viewed')->withTimestamps();
 }` But it is still returning no values?